# How to provide basic_auth in prometheus using helm?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, grafana

I use helm to install Prometheus on my GKE cluster but i can't add my endpoint with my credetionals.
There are no fields in values.yaml where i can add it.
I add my endpoint to additionalServiceMonitors:
but there are no field to add credetionals.

Comment: Are you having troubles with TLS auth, thats why you want basic authentication ?

Answer (score -1):

I assume from `prometheus` you mean the `prometheus` server itself. I see in the [documentation](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/prometheus#configuration) for `prometheus` helm charts that you can see all the configurable options for your charts with:

```
helm show values <name of chart>
```

This will help you find the right value to change to mention your authentication endpoint, perhaps.

Otherwise, you might be required to use `ServiceAccount` based configuration, where your authentication `Secret` will be used by the `ServiceAccount` for authentication.

Answer (score -1):

Check here: https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/prometheus-community/prometheus
You should get the configuration file as shown here: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/
Under scrape_confg section you can specify:

```
# Configures the protocol scheme used for requests.
[ scheme: <scheme> | default = http ]

# Optional HTTP URL parameters.
params:
  [ <string>: [<string>, ...] ]

# Sets the `Authorization` header on every scrape request with the
# configured username and password.
# password and password_file are mutually exclusive.
#HERE YOU SET CREDENTIALS
 basic_auth:
  [ username: <string> ]
  [ password: <secret> ]
  [ password_file: <string> ]

# Sets the `Authorization` header on every scrape request with
# the configured credentials.
authorization:
  # Sets the authentication type of the request.
  [ type: <string> | default: Bearer ]
  # Sets the credentials of the request. It is mutually exclusive with
  # `credentials_file`.
  [ credentials: <secret> ]
  # Sets the credentials of the request with the credentials read from the
  # configured file. It is mutually exclusive with `credentials`.
  [ credentials_file: <filename> ]

# Optional OAuth 2.0 configuration.
# Cannot be used at the same time as basic_auth or authorization.
oauth2:
  [ <oauth2> ]
```